# Beginner Trying a complex & tiered if and while statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

New to Python, trying to see why my tiered if and while statements aren't working.  Based off of Trinket, my code is blowing up at my second 'if' statement.
[Trinket Code](https://trinket.io/python/ae48917b80)

This is what I have:

```
MIN_VALUE = 2
MAX_VALUE = 100
input_number = input(
    'Enter a number between {} and {}: '.format( MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE )
)

if input_number.isdigit():

    userDigitalNumber = int(input_number)

        if ((userDigitalNumber >= MIN_VALUE) and (userDigitalNumber =< MAX_VALUE)):

            while ( range( 1, ( userDigitalNumber + 1 )  )
                totalSum = totalSum + userDigitalNumber
                userDigitalNumber -= userDigitalNumber

else:
    'I''m sorry but your number is not a whole digital number.  Please try again.'
    sys.exit( 1 )

print(
    'The sum of all integers between 1 and {} is {}.'.format( userDigitalNumber, totalSum )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not properly aligned. It should be aligned on the same level as `userDigitalNumber = ...` statement.

Comment: :) I had the same problem when started python with a C background. Also, another hint before you start swearing why, do not mix hard tabs and soft tabs (tabs represented as spaces) on the same file, you will get indentation errors again.

Comment: `=<` should be `<=`. You also have a bunch of parentheses inside the if and while you don't need. You are forgetting `:` at the end of your while. And you never initially declared `totalSum`

Comment: And if it answers your question you might want to accept it as the answer :).

Comment: wow.... lots of errors.......  ii'm using NotePad++ to write all of this.  i see a ton of errors.  thank you all

Comment: time limit on the accepting of the answer.  have to wait another minute (literally)

Comment: Use a python IDE (like pycharm or spyder) or text editor+python plugin (sublime+anaconda or atom+python plugin). They highlight the errors and help with indentation.

Comment: Thanks!  still throwing an error on my while. https://trinket.io/python/0f8516fea1

Comment: That is now how do a while loop in Python. You want something like  `while i < num: i+=1`

Comment: It fails cause you have no boolean condition on this while loop, just an iterator. And I never used whiles even in C :). A while can be done with a for loop ;) try `for _ in range(userDigitalNumber):`.

Comment: @idjaw That would be inefficient both computationally and memory wise than a for loop with (x)range and a dummy variable :).

Comment: @JohnSmith It was a extremely simplified example on how to structure a while loop in Python. As is, it's an infinite loop. :)

Comment: Missing parenthesis. It should be `for amount in range( 1, ( userDigitalNumber + 1 )):`, which actually is equivalent to `for _ in range(userDigitalNumber):`, the`_` is a null variable since you are not using the iterated value anywhere. PS: You really need a python editor :).

Comment: And for infinite loops do `while True:`

Comment: @KevinFischer The for loop has a syntax error, however, the for loop provided to you is also incorrect. You want `for i in range(1, userDigitalNumber + 1): total_sum += i`.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks everyone!  I learned a ton, even with such simple code!

Answer (score 1):

It can not work because Python doesn't handle '=<'!

Change it with '<='.

Fixed:

```
if ((userDigitalNumber >= MIN_VALUE) and (userDigitalNumber =< MAX_VALUE)):
```

And yeah, also... It won't work because of its wrong indentation level.